# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS No Password Prompt after update, can't login

Tags: 18.04, login

I recently logged into a VM running ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS server and found I was having networking issues.  General solution to these issues was a reboot of the VM but this time when it came back, netplan was just gone as though it had been uninstalled which broke my entire networking stack.  I then attempted to side load all the dependencies to reinstall netplan via .deb packages and updated dependencies and after a going down a few of these packages, I had to reboot the VM and now I can no longer login.  I've found various topics around login loops with the desktop and going to the tty terminal but i'm already there and I don't get in the loop of username, password repeat.  I now never see a password prompt.  I get to the login screen, i type the user name and it sits, and comes back with the username again.  I have no idea what to do now because an auto update broke my networking and an update of a package broke my ability to login.

Comment: Can you provide more specific details about the original problems and go into complete detail all of the exact tasks that you did trying to fix it and beyond?  Because it sounds like your attempts to fix the original issue are the cause of your current issues.  We will need to know exactly what you did with clear, unambiguous details in order to diagnose the issue.  Provide all actions, commands, etc.

Comment: This is a tty login, no desktop or GUI interface.

Comment: The original problem came after a restart of the VM showed the interfaces no longer configured with their settings.  Attempting to run netplan apply showed netplan was no longer installed.  I then mounted a USB drive to the VM with the netplan.io package to manually install this. 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/netplan.io.  This had some additional dependencies not installed so I began going down the line of updating those in the same manner. libnetplan0, libsystemd0, python3-yaml, systemd, libc6, locales, libc_bin.  Most of these were just upgrades and already there.

Comment: I believe after an attempt to install libc_bin an error showed up and It was as if I had lost my session even though I was still partially connected.  I then restarted the VM to attempt to resolve that error and that's where the login issue presented itself.

Comment: FYI: If your system reported itself as 18.04.5 then you'd not applied updates or monitored it very closely; an upgraded system has reported itself as 18.04.6 for some time (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ shows ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that date).   It does sound like you created the issue and aren't running *bionic* any longer as installing a *focal* package also requires the *deps* to be *focal* (libsystemd0 wasn't usable in *bionic* for the *focal* etc...)

Comment: Maybe the login issue was created by installing package upgraded out of order.  However, the complete loss of the netplan package when no updates occurred is what caused me to attempt this.  If I had no network tools how could I ever hope to update anything any more? Not really sure how one package update breaks the login ability.  Seems a bit fragile.